# Heroku app infinitely loading JS files when accessing the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I am making a web app:front-end in Angular and back-end in Rails.

When I deploy the app and try to access the page, I see that my heroku app is infinitely looping to get all javascript files. I only see blank page when I access my address

Here are part of what I see on heroku logs console(I just copy&paste first item to make the second item just to give you an idea what's happening):

```
2016-06-14T00:59:39.473740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public/js/controllers/Contact/Ctrl2.js" host=(host) request_id=(request_id) fwd="ip_address" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1592
2016-06-14T00:59:39.473740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public/js/controllers/Contact/Ctrl1.js" host=(host) request_id=(request_id) fwd="ip_address" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1592
```

Weird part is that when I access my website in incognito mode, it loads fine. I'm not sure why it is not being loaded in normal state browser.

And I eventually get an error saying:

```
angular.js:13642 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.error (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:13642:24)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:10287:18
    at invokeLinkFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:9759:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:9156:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:8459:13)
    at publicLinkFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:8339:30)
    at lazyCompilation (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:8677:25)
    at boundTranscludeFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:8476:16)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js:9206:20)
    at z (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js:6:362)

    angular.js:13642 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Edited:
The script I'm adding to `index.html` is

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, so you know there's a loop in the dependencies right... so now you just need to find out where.

Comment: @TarynEast, How can I find where the loop is being made? First of all, I'm not sure why loop is made when I'm just adding JS files in index.html. I edited what I'm adding to index.html.

Comment: That's a good question to which i do't have the answer. I'd start looking at what you changed, and what's being included... and where else it might be included.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a problem with the browser cache.

Try to clear it , I got sames problems when i check local version and production of my website.

Hope it was helpful !